# cambiar parametros a boton en wxpython

Tags: python, python-3.x

HOla buenas tengo una duda acerca de como cambiar parametros a un boton en wxpython. Me explico:
Tengo una ventana con una lista desplegable con algunos colores y  tengo un boton mas abajo que dice "OK"

La idea es que el usuario seleccione algun color de la lista y luego le de al boton "OK".

Si el usuario selecciona el color blanco se debe abrir un pop-up con un mensaje de error.
Si selecciona algun otro color se debe cerrar la ventana.
Aqui el codigo en python:
import wx

```
class ventana(wx.App):


    def OnInit(self):
        frame = crear_ventana()
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Centre()
        return True

####SI EL USUARIO SELECCIONA BLANCO Y LE DA OK DEBE APARECER ESTA 
VENTAN:#######


class ventana_error(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, padre):

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, padre, wx.NewId(),
                           title="Error", size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        boton = wx.Button(panel, label="entendido",
                      pos=(125, 37), size=(70, 25))
        boton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.llamar)
        self.Centre()
        normal = wx.StaticText(
            panel, -1, "Seleccione otro color", pos=(75, 15), style=wx.ALL)
        # self.entrada_texto=wx.TextCtrl(panel,value="",pos=(5,27),size= 
               (5,5),style=wx.TE_LEFT)

    def llamar(self, event):
        self.Close(True)


#################VENTANA PRINCIPAL: ##################

class crear_ventana(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title="Seleccione colores", size= 
          (200, 200),
                      pos=(100, 10), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ 
  (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX))
       panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        boton1 = wx.Button(panel1, label="OK",
                       pos=(50, 100), size=(50, 25))

        opciones = [u"Blanco", u"Rojo", u"Verde"]
        self.opciones = wx.Choice(
           panel1, wx.ID_ANY, choices=opciones, pos=(50, 50), size=(100, 
             25))
    self.opciones.SetSelection(-1)

    #####AQUI ESTA EL PROBLERMA:######
    boton1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.llamar_ventana1)
    # Lo que necesito es cambiar ese llamar_ventana1
    # por llamar_ventana2 pero dependiendo de lo que el
    # usuario seleccione

    dec = self.opciones.Bind(
        wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.Choice)  # esto se me ocurrio
    # pero resulta que solo funciona una vez al ejecutarse
    # tal vez que me devuelva un valor distinto cada vez que
    # el usuario cambie de seleccion
    # dec almacena eso que el usuario selecciona

    print("dec: ")
    print(dec)

    def Choice(self, event):  # Esta es la funcion para verificar lo que se 
    selecciono
      global numerox

       opcion_seleccionada = self.opciones.GetStringSelection()
       opcion_seleccionada_uno = self.opciones.GetSelection()
       print(opcion_seleccionada)
       print(opcion_seleccionada_uno)
       return opcion_seleccionada_uno

     def llamar_ventana1(self, event):  # si el usuario selecciona blanco
        # llamar a esta funcion
        ventana2 = ventana_error(self)
        ventana2.ShowModal()
        ventana2.Destroy()


     def llamar_ventana2(self, event):  # si selecciona otro color llamar a 
          esta funcion
          self.Destroy()


app1 = ventana(0)
app1.MainLoop()
```

Si porfavor alguien sabe como hacer eso me explica.
Estare aqui todo el tiempo gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio vas bien encaminado, pero en vez de intentar cambiar la callback asociada al botón dependiendo de la opción seleccionada es más simple usar un wrapper. Dado que la acción debe tener lugar cuando se pulsa el botón, no cuando se produce la selección, simplemente usa un condicional en la callback y llama a un método u otro en función de la opción actual del `Choice`:

```
import wx



class App(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = SeleccionColores()
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Centre()
        return True


class VentanaError(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, padre, mensage=""):

        super().__init__(padre, wx.NewId(),
                         title="Error", size=(300, 100)
                         )
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        boton = wx.Button(panel, label="entendido", size=(70, 25))
        msg = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, mensage, style=wx.ALL)
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        main_sizer.Add(msg, 0, wx.CENTER)
        main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        main_sizer.Add(boton, 2, wx.CENTER)
        main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        boton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cerrar)
        self.Centre()

    def cerrar(self, event):
        self.Close(True)


class SeleccionColores(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, -1, title="Seleccione colores",
                         size= (200, 200), pos=(100, 10),
                         style=(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ 
                                (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | 
                                 wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)))


        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        boton = wx.Button(panel, label="OK", pos=(50, 100), size=(50, 25))

        opciones = ["Blanco", "Rojo", "Verde"]
        self.opciones = wx.Choice(panel, wx.ID_ANY, choices=opciones,
                                  pos=(50, 50), size=(100, 35)
                                  )
        self.opciones.SetSelection(-1)
        boton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.seleccion)

    def seleccion(self, event):
        opcion_seleccionada = self.opciones.GetStringSelection()
        if not opcion_seleccionada:
            self.mostrar_dialogo_error("Seleccione un color")
        elif opcion_seleccionada == "Blanco":
            self.mostrar_dialogo_error("Seleccione otro color")
        else:
            self.cerrar()

    def mostrar_dialogo_error(self, msg): 
        ventana2 = VentanaError(self, mensage=msg)
        ventana2.ShowModal()
        ventana2.Destroy()

    def cerrar(self, event=None):
        self.Destroy()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app1 = App(0)
    app1.MainLoop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He modificado los nombres de clases y métodos y algunas otras cosa para seguir en lo posible las convenciones de estilo de [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?), hay otros retoques como el uso de `super` para llamar al inicilizador de la clase padre o el uso de *sizers* en el diálogo del error.

Comment: Uff amigo gracias eres un genio me has salvado la vida jeje 
Solo una pregunta mas por que en la funcion "cerrar(self, event=None):" pones ese event=None??

Comment: @metamax es un parámetro con un valor por defecto, puedes llamar a `cerrar` con `self.cerrar()`  y con `self.cerrar(evento)`, la utilidad en estos casos es que el método pueda ser llamado como callback de un evento (se le pasa el evento obligatoriamente) o puedes llamarla sin necesidad de un evento como ocurre en este caso (`event` será `None` y no tenemos que pasar el parámetro obligatoriamente).